# Spinnaker - Azure keyvault integration

Tags: azure-keyvault, spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to integrate azure key vault with spinnaker and didn't find any links/resources. Essentially my jobs should be able to access the secrets which are stored in azure keyvault.

Has anyone tried it ?

Answer (score 0):

Right now Spinnaker integrates with Vault only for secret management. 
One way i found to integrate Spinnaker with AWS Secrets manager is through the use of Cloud Formation templates that resolve the secret at runtime.

You could try with terraform and the spinnaker terraformer. 
If you ever need you might need to create a simple Java plugin in spinnaker to achieve this. There is guidance in the following [medium.com article](https://blog.spinnaker.io/digging-into-oss-contribution-with-spinnaker-gardening-days-2020-bc308040587?gi=13815696ebd6).